# Google Maps API integrated in an OOP way

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to implement Google Maps API in an OOP way.

First, I create the class and then I add some methods.

However, in the Load() method, I get an error in fireBug

> "google.load is not a function"

and I also getting this error if I'm trying to execute it in the constructor.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

B.R Carl

```
// Class Map
function Map() {
    var self = this;

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    //script.src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MyAPIKey=self.Load";
    script.src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MyAPIKey";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    //google.load("maps", "2", {"callback" : self.Loaded}); //This does not work
}

Map.prototype.Load = function() {    
    //AJAX API is loaded successfully.
    google.load("maps", "2", {"callback" : self.Loaded()});
}

Map.prototype.Loaded = function() {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(11.11, 22.22), 5);
}

map = new Map;
map.Load();
```

Comment: You need to wait until the script has loaded

Comment: Unrelated, but recommend you use Google Maps API 3 instead of API 2, which has been deprecated since May 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code. The error you are getting is causes by the first problem:

1. You are calling `google.load()` (inside `map.Load()`) before the script containing Google Loader is loaded. You have to use callback to be notified when the script is loaded (see the dynamic loading section in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/#Dynamic) of Google Loader, notice especially the `callback` parameter in `script.src` value). You simply can't use `google.load()` function before the callback is called.
2. In `google.load` function you are setting the callback wrongly. It seems you want `map.Loaded()` function to be called as the callback. But you are doing something different. You are calling `map.Loaded()` instantly and passing its return value as the name of the callback function. And since `map.Loaded()` isn't returning any value you haven't specified any callback. To fix this remove the brackets - use `self.Loaded` instead of `self.Loaded()`.
3. You should not use `self` when you specify callback function. Callback function have to be globally visible. When you use `self`, you are referencing the global scope. If you have defined a global function named `Loaded` it is called instead of `map.Loaded()` function. If you haven't defined any global function of that name, you get an error.

To fix the prolems your code should contain something like this (provided that the `map` variable is globally visible):

```
// Class Map
function Map() {
    var self = this;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MyAPIKey&callback=map.Load";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

Map.prototype.Load = function() {    
    //AJAX API is loaded successfully.
    google.load("maps", "2", {"callback" : map.Loaded});
}

Map.prototype.Loaded = function() {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(11.11, 22.22), 5);
}

map = new Map();
```